# I have an issue trying to install parcel from NPM on VScode Terminal and also on the Node.js Command Prompt

Tags: npm, parceljs

While trying to install parcel on npm (using `npm i parcel --save-dev`), I get a list of error messages. How do I solve this problem?

```
PS C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter> npm i parcel --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility      
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\lmdb
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\AYINDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\install-ef76ed04.cmd
npm ERR! C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build-optional-packages\index.js:77       
npm ERR!   throw new Error('No native build was found for ' + target + '\n    attempted loading from: ' + dir + ' and package:' +
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=ia32 runtime=node abi=93 uv=1 libc=glibc node=16.17.1
npm ERR!     attempted loading from: C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\lmdb and package: @lmdb/lmdb-win32-ia32
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at Function.load.path (C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build-optional-packages\index.js:77:9)
npm ERR!     at load (C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build-optional-packages\index.js:29:25)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build-optional-packages\build-test.js:19:19)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The failure above indicates the primary issue with the native builds which are included for all major platforms. Will now attempt to build the package locally in case this can be resolved by re-compiling.
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used        
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used 
to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use 
Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation 
to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:408:5) 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:420:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28) 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\Desktop\17-Modern-JS-Modules-Tooling\starter\node_modules\lmdb
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AYINDE SODIQ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-23T13_24_26_860Z-debug-0.log
```